# Derivation of GDA being equivalent to logistic regression

Tags: regression, self-study, logistic, mathematical-statistics

Whilst looking at the answer to this question:
[Gaussian Discriminant Analysis and sigmoid function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251069/gaussian-discriminant-analysis-and-sigmoid-function?newreg=b4707382f46642f6b61c964479517449)

I was wondering how they got from
$$log(\frac{\pi_1}{\pi_0}) -(x - \mu_1)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu_1)/2 + (x - \mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu_0)/2
$$

to

$$
log(\frac{\pi_1}{\pi_0}) + (\mu_1 - \mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x + \frac{1}{2}(\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0 - \mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1)
$$

More specifically - I don't understand how they got this term:
$$(\mu_1 - \mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall from matrix rules that:

(1) the matrix multiplication operator is distributive with respect to addition, meaning $A(B+C)=AB+AC$

(2) the transpose operator respects addition, meaning $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$.

Starting with the leftmost term (neglect the $\frac{1}{2}$ for now): from (1) we get
$$(x-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_0)=(x-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x-(x-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0$$

and from (2):
$$(x-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x=x^T\Sigma^{-1}x-\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}x$$

and so the leftmost term can be written as

$$\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_0)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x^T\Sigma^{-1}x-\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}x-x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0+\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0\right)$$

adding up both terms:
$$-(x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_1)/2+(x-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_0)/2=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
-x^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}x+x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1-\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1+x^T\Sigma^{-1}x-\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}x-x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0+\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0
\right)=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}x-\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}x+x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1-x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0-\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1+\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0
\right)=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
(\mu_1-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x+x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)-\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1+\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0
\right)
$$

Now, note three things: (a) the transpose of a scalar is a scalar itself; (b) $\left((\mu_1-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x\right)^T=x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)$ and (c) $x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)$ is a scalar, so we can add up:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(
(\mu_1-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x+x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)-\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1+\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0
\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(2(\mu_1-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x
-\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1+\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0
\right)$$
$$=(\mu_1-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0
-\mu_1^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1
\right)$$

$\blacksquare$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise $\left((\mu_1-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}x\right)^T=x^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1-\mu_0)
$ was a scalar!